# Program is based on a man walking around a city (Perl)

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a file that contains the letters 'n', 's', 'e', 'w'.

How do I look for these letters and add them to a variable called `$ns` and `$ew`,

- `$ns` means to add 'n' or subtract 's'.
- `$ew` means to add 'e' or subtract 'w'.

This is what I have:

```
open (FILE, 'randwalk1')

or die "Could not open file";

my $ns = 0;

my $ew = 0;

while (my $file1 = <FILE>) {
    if ($file1 =~ /n+/) {
        $ns = $ns + 1;
    } elsif ($file1 =~ /s/) {
        $ns = $ns - 1;
    } elsif ($file1 =~ /e/) {
        $ew = $ew + 1;
    } elsif ($file1 =~ /w/) {
        $ew = $ew - 1;
    }
}
```

The input file (`randwalk1`) looks like:

```
ensweswewnnewwwsweenwsssssnewwennnesewewwewsnnewwwsewsenssns‌
newnwssswennesnseewn‌​wsnwnwnnwwwewes
neesnwnsenwsnnnewwswnnneesswssnswenwsnnwewswwsnennneeeeswewe‌​
```

Comment: What problem are you having? What does your data look like?

Comment: It seems that the code cannot add or subtract n,w,e,s from reading the file. I do not know if its the pattern or something else. Also the data looks somewhat like this: nnnwnsensnewsnsnswenswnesnweswneswesnwe

Comment: Add a sample file to the question.

Comment: The sample file (randwalk1) looks like this: ensweswewnnewwwsweenwsssssnewwennnesewewwewsnnewwwsewsenssnsnewnwssswennesnseewnwsnwnwnnwwwewes
neesnwnsenwsnnnewwswnnneesswssnswenwsnnwewswwsnennneeeeswewewnwnswnnnssnnwnsnnnsenwwnsweeneeewn
nswewnenwnesssnnsseswewensswnseessnwswwnesewnnnnweeensnweswnsesnwwwneeeweswswsnnwnsesnneensenen
wnsswwnneswwsennsewswwwnewwwsnswnwweesewwwwsnnsenwewssssnseenwwsswneseswwnwwwwwnesnesnwenesnwns
ensweswewnnewwwsweenwsssssnewwennnesewewwewsnnewwwsewsenssnsnewnwssswennesnseewnwsnwnwnnwwwewes
neesnwnsenwsnnnewwswnnneesswssnswenwsnnwewswwsnennneeeeswewewnwnswnnns

Comment: Edit your answer to provide additional information, don't add comments. Not all comments are always shown, and formatting is poor in comments. Put everything in one place, make it easy to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You check if the line has an `n`, you find one, then you ignore the rest of the line. You need to check each character of the line.

```
my $home_returns = 0;
my $ns = 0;
my $ew = 0;
while (my $line = <>) {
   chomp($line);
   for my $char (split //, $line) {
      if    ($char eq "n") { ++$ns; }
      elsif ($char eq "s") { --$ns; }
      elsif ($char eq "e") { ++$ew; }
      elsif ($char eq "w") { --$ew; }

      ++$home_returns if $ns == 0 && $ew == 0;
   }
}
```

or

```
my $home_returns = 0;
my %counts = map { $_ => 0 } qw( n s e w );
while (my $line = <>) {
   chomp($line);
   for my $char (split //, $line) {
      ++$counts{$char};
      ++$home_returns
         if $counts{n} == $counts{s}
         && $counts{e} == $counts{w};
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. This really helps. I just have one more question related to this. Imagine if this program was a man walking according to this code in a grid going n,s,w,e. I want to find how many times the man would return to the origin. Thanks again.